# Sencha Touch 2 Field Focus

Tags: extjs4, sencha-touch-2

Does anyone know the Sencha Touch 2 equivalent of ExtJS4's:

```
form.getForm().findField("myfield");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use form.getValues(); assuming you can get the form element... if you needs to do that use refs... on my mobile rigjt now, i can post more sample code later if necessary

Answer (score 0):

I use that way:
`var field = vorm.down("textfield[name=username]");`

Example:
`form.down("selectfield[name=username]").setLabel('User');`
`form.down("selectfield[name=username]").setValue('email@te');`
`form.down("selectfield[name=username]").setPlaceHolder('email@test.com');`